# Which is the feasible way of storing data?

Tags: android

I am developing android app that stores the data for poems, i can access data from the string.xml file, and i can also build SQLite database. So what will be the most easiest way in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is some ways to store data in Android, some answers has mentioned SharedPreferences, TextFiles, or SqLite.

I think that SharedPreferences is not the best choice for you, due that you will store poems, I guess that you need some attributes for each poem.

SqLite and Realm are very similar, there is possible store many data types, Realm is a library that allows create and access to databases in a way really easy.
However the easier way that I knows is using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) , it's really easy to use. I hope my answer helped you.

Note: sorry for my bad English :(.

Comment: Hi Erick, I really appreciate your answer, yes realm is easiest way, i also wanted to know about its time complexities in accessing data and performance. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Which option you chose is highly dependent on the types of data you are storing.

Your `strings.xml` file (and other resource files) should be used for static content. Simple text that you want to display to the user fits in well here.

A SQLite database is useful if you have a large amount of structured data. If you have lists of objects (like a list of trivia questions and answers), that might be better suited to a database.

SQLite databases are also modifiable by your app at runtime (resource files such as `strings.xml` are not), so if you are storing user-inputted data, either a database or `SharedPreferences` (key-value pairs) might be more appropriate.